# MSR Orleans, How does PlacementStrategy work?

Tags: orleans

In Orleans, how do the PlacementStrategy’s work? I see that there are several implementations of the PlacementStrategy including RandomPlacement, PreferLocalPlacement, ActivationCountBasedPlacement and StatelessWorkerPlacement.

I have a few question from how to use these to how are they implemented? How do I specify that a call should be Prefer-Local vs RandomPlacement?

I am looking through the code and I do not see the code which chooses one execution path versus another based on these placement strategies. Where does that happen?

Comment: There is an issue about placement strategies, this unveils some details: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/96 But I'm not an expert, I forwarded your question to Gitter (https://gitter.im/dotnet/orleans).

Comment: There is some more details: http://richorama.github.io/blog/2015/01/02/grain-placement-in-orleans/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are more details by Richard here: http://richorama.github.io/blog/2015/01/02/grain-placement-in-orleans/
We should, and will, move this into our docs here on github.io.

How to use: add an attribute [PreferLocal] on the grain class.

The code: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/src/OrleansRuntime/Core/Dispatcher.cs#L555

SelectOrAddActivation(..., strategy) forwards to the specific placement director, based on the specified placement policy.